# mongodb query get printers not inspected?

Tags: mongodb

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jkZXn3MiYo5)

I have a printer collection and printerInspection collection  that contain the printer id and the date it was inspected.
How can I find what printer was not inspected at 08-23-2019 (in this example only printer 2 and 1 got inspected at 08-23-2019...
current solution i have is pulling both collections and filtering in java but its very slow, looking for a mongo query solution

```
db={
  "printer": [
    {
      "printerId": 0
    },
    {
      "printerId": 1
    },
    {
      "printerId": 2
    },
    {
      "printerId": 3
    },
    {
      "printerId": 4
    },

  ],
  "printerInspection": [
    {
      "printerId": 2,
      "date": "08-23-2019"
    },
    {
      "printerId": 2,
      "date": "08-22-2019"
    },
    {
      "printerId": 2,
      "date": "08-21-2019"
    },
    {
      "printerId": 1,
      "date": "08-23-2019"
    },
    {
      "printerId": 3,
      "date": "08-22-2019"
    },
    {
      "printerId": 3,
      "date": "08-21-2019"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use aggregate pipeline as below
1. We club all available printers and printers who were inspected on a specified day
2. The difference of array of printers and inspectedPrinters

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      printers: {
        $map: {
          input: "$printer",
          as: "item",
          in: "$$item.printerId"
        }
      },
      inspectedPrinters: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$printerInspection",
              as: "item",
              cond: {
                $eq: [
                  "$$item.date",
                  "08-23-2019"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          as: "item2",
          in: "$$item2.printerId"
        },

      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      notInspected: {
        $setDifference: [
          "$printers",
          "$inspectedPrinters"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: In your link, you define db={printer:[]} and while accessing db.printer.aggregate([]) it only accesses printer array that's why data is coming null

Comment: can you show me with new link? if its working i will accept.